# Parse.com Data export bug

Tags: android, ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to export my data on Parse but the system seems like it's getting stuck on the first step: "Waiting to begin.." as you can see in this picture :

[image]

Has anyone encountered this problem? Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It actually ended up working, I received an email after about 3 hours with the link to download the backup